# Free domain for static public IP address

Tags: dns, subdomain, digital-ocean

I have a personal website on digitalocean that is assigned a public IP addr, say, `128.148.32.11`. It is a static IP address. Is it possible to get a free domain for this IP address?

I do not care about the URL of the domain as long as it is free. Preferably, the domain remains free for a long time and one need to re-register every now and then.

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with the question? Why the negative vote? Hope to know so that I can improve my questions in future.

Comment: I believe it's because StackOverflow is mainly focussed on questions about coding, while this question is about hosting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use http://freedns.afraid.org/.

Register for a free account. Then, add a sub-domain (choose whatever suits you) and put your digitalocean IP address `128.148.32.11` into the Destination field.

You're ready to go.

You do not need to care about the dynamic DNS stuff because your digitalocean VM ip address is a static one. Makes things even simpler for you.